# Executing a node script via crontab

Tags: node.js, cron

can anyone help me figure out why my cron scheduling doesnt work?:

0 8 * * * /usr/bin/node /home/globein_ext/mysql-slack-bot/index.js

I'm trying to run a node app each day at 8am. I locate node first and then access the file I want run. Nothing seems to happen though.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What happens when you run the command ("/usr/bin/node /home/globein_ext/mysql-slack-bot/index.js") directly in the console?

Comment: Ah it says @slack/bolt requires at least version 10.13.0 of Node, please upgrade
but when I check which version I have it says v14.4.0

Comment: So your problem is not related to cron, but rather to your app

Comment: I've figured how to get the command running with no node version error: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/node /home/globein_ext/mysql-slack-bot/index.js but when I schedule it with cron nothing happens